# How to allow http request from one unsecured url but disallow all other http requests. App transport security Settings

Tags: ios, encryption

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>appname-dev.domain.org</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm trying to get appname-dev.domain.org to work but appname.staging.domain.org not to work unless its https.

Would the above work? I can't really test since we have https backend and one for dev which is not http and one for https. Would thus app get rejected by apple for allowing all http non secure requests. It does however allow the appname-dev.domain.org but I'm not sure it dissallows appname-staging.domain.org

The only non http request must be from appname-dev.domain.org all other must be blocked.

Comment: The best approach is to change the Domain based on Envrionment using UserDefined Settings in 'Build Settings' pane

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if allowed domain is `appname-dev.domain.org` as the only domain for nonsecure http traffic that `appname.staging.domain.org` would not work if it is not secure.

And Apple will not reject your app if you add a few domains for non-secure traffic.